# How to execute friend class?

Tags: c++, class, friend

I tried to realize the friend class to provide the members's value for the member of another class.

I' ve tried to make the object of `class Friend` and defined it as `Attempt`'s argument and after replace `&Friend::fri` to `object.fri()` but it was not compiled also.

```
 class Friend {
  public:
    int val = 0;
int fri() {
    val = 456;
    return val;         
          }
friend class Partner;
 };

 class Partner {    
  public:
//(corrected) Friend Object;
int Attempt() {
    std::cout << "The value from the friend class: " << 
     &Friend::fri /*(corrected) Object.fri()*/<<"\n"; // '&' was requred by compiler to make pointer to 
                        //the member
    return 0;
      }
 };
```

I expected `Attempt` to write the value from `fri()`. But there's 1 and I can't undertand where is this 1 from.

Answer (score 0):

The friend keyword simply lets non-member functions have access to private/protected members of another class. Unless your method is static, or inheritance is involved, you're still going to need an object to call that method. Take for example:

```
Friend f;
int Attempt(){
    std::cout << "The value from the friend class: " << f.fri();
}
```

This will produce the output you're expected.

Comment: Thanks,  indeed it returned required value.

Comment: @Konstantin Glad it helped. Feel free to mark it as correct if it solved your problem in case someone else runs across this problem in the future :)

Comment: previous time I corrected code and after somebody wrote not to do this, now I really don’t know what to do after the problem’s been solved) Guess if I  make remarks in the code it’ll be the best solution)